# validation.xml change mask value on condition

Tags: validation, struts-1

I am working on struts server side validation(version 1.2).  I have used validwhen several times. I have 2 textboxes that submit to server. text1(value comes here from a drop down selection) can have name or id. text 2 holds its value. I have to write validation on text2. Is there a way where i can change mask var-value in validwhen ? i.e if text1 value is name then text2's mask should be a regex for name(alphanumeric and space). if text1 value is id then text2's mask should be a regex for id(only numbers). Is there a way this can be achieved? I don't think we can write 2 different validation on same field.
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

IMO validation like that belongs on the Java side.

You can either wrap it up in a custom validator if it will be used across the app, or as part of the form's validation method, where  you could also combine it with standard XML validation.